# Installing OSX Lion from USB after Linux install

Tags: macos, usb, startup, install

I installed Elementary OS on my MacBook 4,1. I now want to revert to MacOS Lion. I created a bootable USB, which is recognised when booting from another Mac, but the MacBook 4,1 does not recognise it. When booting and holding option, I only see one option - "EFI Boot", which boots into Elementary. I've tried both USB ports, no difference. Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried a PRAM (see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063) and SMC Reset (seehttps://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295 - For your Mac: Shut down your Mac, remove the battery, press and hold the power button for 5 seconds, put the battery back in and try to boot while holding option again)?

Comment: @KevinGrabher unfortunately that hasn't changed anything. I followed your instructions with the battery, and also the cmd-option-p-r keys (and waited for the second chime)

Comment: You can install Snow Leopard from a DVD, then upgrade to Lion for free. Downloading an Snow Leopard iso for free should be simple enough, however there is not enough information in your question to tell if you can burn to a DL DVD.